# What's the measure of the segment $QC$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In a triangle $ABC$ with centroid $G$, on $AB$ and $BC$ the points $P$ and $Q$ are located respectively such that $BP = 4AP$ and $BQ = 8$.
Calculate $QC$, If $P, G ~and~ Q$ are collinear.(answer: $\frac{16}{3}$)

Solution by geometry.

My progress:
[image]

I do not have many ideas in this exercise

Try Menelaus: $\triangle CPQ-BD\\
CI.PG.8 = IP.GQ.(8+QC)\\
\triangle ABD-PC\\
x.BI.CD=4x.DI.AC\implies BI = 8DI\\
BI = BG+GI ~and ~DG = GI+DI\implies DI = DG-GI\\
BG+GI = 8(GI+DI)\rightarrow 2GD +GI = 8GD -8GI \implies GI = \frac{2GD}{3}\\
 $

but I did not see much utility...

Comment: Please always draw a picture that reflects as good as possible the given situation. In the given picture it does not look like $PB=4PA$.

Comment: Is the answer $QC=16/3$ verified? Not $QC=6$?

Comment: @dan_fulea yes I think it should be $QC = 6$. I get the same.

Comment: @dan_fulea  as I have mentioned several times the transcripts are exact of the question and the templates...probably an error in the template which is not uncommon to find in this book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D'$ be the intersection of lines $PGQ\cap ADC$.
Menelaus for $\Delta BAD$ w.r.t. the transversal line $PGD'$ gives
$$
1=
\frac{PA}{PB}\cdot
\frac{GB}{GD}\cdot
\frac{D'D}{D'A}
=
\left(-\frac 14\right)\cdot
\left(-2\right)\cdot
\frac{D'D}{D'A}
=\frac 12\ .
$$
This shows which is the location of the point $D'$ on $AC$,
it is so that
$$
D'A=AD=DC\ .
$$
A faithful picture is needed. (Please compare with the given picture...)

[image: math stackexchange 4276510]

Now apply Menelaus in $\Delta BAC$ w.r.t. the transversal $D'PQ$ to get
$$
1 = 
\frac{D'A}{D'C}\cdot
\frac{QC}{QB}\cdot
\frac{PB}{PA}
=
\frac 13\cdot 
\frac{QC}{QB}\cdot
(-4)
\ ,
$$
which clears the location of the point $Q$ on $BC$.

$\square$

---

Here is one more picture, showing that when $BQ$ is realized as "four pieces", then $QC$ is "three (same) pieces."

[image: math stackexchenge 4276510 second picture]

Comment: Reading through your answer, it is much simpler. I complicated it going by OP's diagram.

Answer (score 2):

First apply Menelaus's Theorem in $\triangle ACP$ with traversal $DB$.

$\displaystyle \frac{AB}{BP} \cdot \frac{PI}{IC} \cdot \frac{CD}{DA} = 1$

Find relation between $IP$ and $IC$

Next, apply Menelaus's in $\triangle ABD$ with traversal $PC$.

$\displaystyle \frac{AC}{CD} \cdot \frac{DI}{IB} \cdot \frac{BP}{PA} = 1$

Using $DI = DG - IG, IB =IG + GB$, find relation between $IG$ and $GB$

Finally, apply Menelaus's in $\triangle BIC$ with traversal $QP$

$\displaystyle \frac{CP}{IP} \cdot \frac{IG}{GB} \cdot \frac{BQ}{QC} = 1$

and that gives you value of $QC$.

Comment: @petaarantes the other answer has a better solution and I think it deserves a tick instead of my answer.